# Use msgread to read specific line

Tags: tcl

I am new user to tcl, only experience this programming script for 4 days.

I tried to access message file. The instructor only introduced msg commands like msgcreate, msgget, msgread.....etc.

This is how file look like:

```
NK1|1|ELIZABETH POTTER^^^^^^L|MOTHER|RIDLEYTON NURSIN
NK1|1|MARK DAVIES^^^^^^L|CARER|C/- CARA Pty.Ltd.^""^WOODVIL8|C2|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
PV1||I|EPIC^^^0014^^084^0014^^EMERGENCY PATIENTS IN CARE|""|||
```

I want to read 3rd line to detemine if the index 5 is O or I.

```
##Field
set field [string match *|O|* [msgget $mh]]
set out "|O|"
if {$field == $out} {
    echo Patient class field: Outpatient
} else {
    echo Patient class fiedl: Inpatient
}
```

I realized this code only read the First line of the file, so it always echo me back the inpatient.

Comment: When you have to use non-standard commands in your code, you need to explain what they do. Note that as `field` gets the return value of `string match`, it will always have either 1 or 0 as value, which will never be equal to `"|O|"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `msgget` will read a single line, which corresponds to a record. Which is fine; it's an abstraction round the standard Tcl command `gets` in all likelihood. (The rest of this answer assumes that this is true.)

Once you've got a record, you've got to split it into the fields, which you can then check the value of. Since it appears that `|` is the record separator, you can split things apart with:

```
set fields [split $record "|"]
```

That produces a list, and you can pick the second element out with:

```
set secondField [lindex $field 1];  # <<< zero-base indexes, like in C
```

Combining these:

```
set fields [split [msgget $mh] "|"]
set out "0"
if {[lindex $fields 1] eq $out} {
    # ...
}
```

Mind you, since you're probably going to be dealing with many fields, the `lassign` command (new in Tcl 8.5, but hopefully you're not on an older version) works wonders:

```
lassign [split [msgget $mh] "|"] code inpatient name status location ...
```

It's for this sort of work where it works best.

<sup>(If you're dealing with fixed-width fields — unlikely, but maybe — then you should `string range` or `scan`.)</sup>